# MySQL `unique_index` with datetime giving error

Tags: mysql, unique-index

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_ps ADD UNIQUE 
`unique_index`(`UserId`,`VillageId`,`SubcategoryId`,date(updatedatetime)
```

giving error

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: the user may not be entered same day that village

Comment: Is there a missing parenthesis or it's just me?

Comment: There is a missing parenthesis and missing error message for further debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use function in index declaration. So you query should be next:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_ps 
ADD UNIQUE unique_index(UserId, VillageId, SubcategoryId, updatedatetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Functional indexes* are implemented in MySQL starting in version 8.0.15. For example you can do:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_ps ADD UNIQUE unique_index(
  UserId, VillageId, SubcategoryId, (date(updatedatetime))
);
```

Remember to write expressions between parenthesis.

Then you can run:

```
insert into tbl_ps (UserId, VillageId, SubcategoryId, updatedatetime) 
  values (1, 2, 3, '2020-03-04 12:34:56'); -- succeeds

insert into tbl_ps (UserId, VillageId, SubcategoryId, updatedatetime) 
  values (1, 2, 3, '2020-03-04 15:16:17'); -- fails!
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cee6f87dde46f4c94678b4e308bcca44).